# FindItems promise in ews-javascript-api does not execute

Tags: node.js, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use ews-javascript-api for reading mail from Exchange server.

However, promise of FindItems is not getting executed.

```
var ews = require('ews-javascript-api');
var ExchangeService = ews.ExchangeService;
var service = new ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new ews.ExchangeCredentials("MY_USERNAME", "MY_PASSWORD");
service.Url = new ews.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");

var items = service.FindItems(ews.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "hasattachment:true",new ews.ItemView(1));

items.then(function(response){

    console.log("RESPONSE");
},function(err){
    console.log("ERROR");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean [ews-javascript-api](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/) (not aws-javascript-api)?

you may be facing issue reported [here](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/issues/111), fix to which is not yet published to latest tag on  npm, you can install `ews-javascript-api@next` to get around for time being.